# how to disable form button in an if condition in a loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have a page where multiple forms are showing from the single table, same form but the different values with some inputs and a button in last in every form.

Is there any way to disable a specific form's button when the a specific value returns a specific amount?

Like I am getting the data from table to show on the page through foreach loop:

```
$userID = $_SESSION['username']['UserID'];
$query = "Select * from tbl_packages";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
mysqli_close($conn);

foreach($result as $data):

    $PkgID = $data['id'];
    $PkgAmount = $data['amount'];
    $PkgFees = $data['fees'];
    $PkgPeriod = $data['period'];
    $ReturningAmount = $data['returnAmount'];
?>
<form 
    action="" 
    class="form-inline" 
    method="POST" 
    id="buyPackage-init"
>
    <input 
        class="form-control form-control-user" 
        name="PkgID" 
        id="PackagegID" 
        value=<?php echo $PkgID?> 
        readonly
    >
    <!-- and more inputs like above... -->
</form>
<?PHP 
    endforeach;
?>
```

and then I am selecting the stored form values from the second table to check if a form data already exist in the table in a loop, like this:

```
$queryCheckPackage = "select status from tbl_lendinglogs where UserID = '$userID'";
$resultCheckPackage = mysqli_query($conn,$queryCheckPackage);
$numCheckPackage = mysqli_num_rows($resultCheckPackage);
$FetchCheckPackage = mysqli_fetch_array($resultCheckPackage);

$value = null;
foreach($resultCheckPackage as $row)
{
    if($row['status'] == 1) {
        //echo $row['status'];
        $value = "disabled";
    } else {
        $value = "enabled";
        //echo "enabled <BR>";
    }                                   
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

And then the button in the form before  tag:

```
<input 
    class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" 
    onclick="return confirm('Confirm befor buy?');" 
    type="submit" 
    id="btn" 
    data-target="#buyPackage" 
    value="Invest" 
    name="bttn-order" 
    <?php echo $value ?>
/>
```

Now what is happening is all the buttons got disabled while there are two forms stored in the table 1 form data status is 0 and the second's status is 1. I want check all the status and then disable the particular form's button which's status is 1 in the stored form table.

Is there any possibilities to do so? I am suck by digging information about this on the internet for long time. and I've tried a lot myself but it disabled all the buttons while in the loop there are two values of status that are '0' and '1'.

<-----------------------Updated And Solved The Question------------------>

Here is the queries with foreach loop

```
$userID = $_SESSION['username']['UserID'];                          
$query = "Select * from tbl_packages";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);


//$buttons = [];

$pkgStatus = null;
$PkgID = 0;
foreach($result as $data):                          
$PkgID = $data['id'];
$PkgAmount = $data['amount'];
$PkgFees = $data['fees'];
$PkgPeriod = $data['period'];
$ReturningAmount = $data['returnAmount'];


$queryCheckPackage = "select * from tbl_lendinglogs where UserID = '$userID' and pkg_id = '$PkgID'";
$resultCheckPackage = mysqli_query($conn,$queryCheckPackage);
$numCheckPackage = mysqli_num_rows($resultCheckPackage);
$FetchCheckPackage = mysqli_fetch_array($resultCheckPackage);
foreach($resultCheckPackage as $row):
$pkgStatus = $row['status'];

?>
```

Here is the Button:

```
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" onclick="return confirm('Confirm befor buy?');" type="submit" id="btn" data-target="#buyPackage" value="Invest" name="bttn-order" <?php if ($pkgStatus == 1) echo 'disabled="disabled"' ?>/>
```

And then I've added end for each at the end of :

```
<?php endforeach; endforeach;?>
```

Thank you very much @Wimanicesir you've helped a lot.

Comment: This can never work? You check each row for it's status but overwrite the variable you saved it in. So the last status will apply to all rows.

Comment: Please make your question more clear. It's not clear what you need to achieve.

Comment: @MerianosNikos, it's pretty clear what he wants though?

Comment: @Wimanicesir Sir can you please please give me a example that where I need to change and how it will work? Yes I am checking for each row and I've checked the data by echo $row of foreach loop in the loop and there is coming all values but its working on the last row value. While I need to do it on all values. So please if you don't mind give it a shot and show an example so this could be helpful for more peoples.

Comment: @Ali I provided a more detailed explanation in an answer. As stated there, if you give me the data in $resultCheckPackage, I could help a little more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is mapping between all the different rows and if they are enabled or disabled.

This code loops your data and checks that field and saves it in a variable named $value:

```
$value = null;

foreach($resultCheckPackage as $row) {
    if($row['status']) {
        $value = "disabled";
    } else {
        $value = "enabled";
    }                                    
}
```

However you overwrite value every time. So $value will be the last result of that query.

The data exists of an id and a boolean. We want to combine these two so we can call them later.

So:

```
$buttons = [];

foreach($resultCheckPackage as $row) {
    if($row['status']) {
        $buttons[$row['id']]= TRUE;
    } else {
        $buttons[$row['id']]= FALSE;
    }                                    
}
```

This will result in an keybased array such as:

```
$buttons['package_id_1' => TRUE, 'package_id_2' => FALSE]
```

Now for the last step is call the right id on the right button.

```
<input 
    class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" 
    onclick="return confirm('Confirm befor buy?');" 
    type="submit" 
    id="btn" 
    data-target="#buyPackage" 
    value="Invest" 
    name="bttn-order" 
    <?php if ($buttons['correct_id']) echo 'disabled="disabled"' ?>
/>
```

It's not copy paste proof, but I think you get the idea :)

I would also advise looking into some kind of template language. This makes data from backend to front end rendering much easier.

Such as: https://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: This is my Query: "select status from tbl_lendinglogs where UserID = 1" and this is the data result: https://prnt.sc/rpio6j and this is my table structure of store packages table named tbl_lendinglogs: https://prnt.sc/rpiphk And here is the tbl_packages from where I am getting the packages data to show on the page through foreach loop: https://prnt.sc/rpiqae  These are the data. If you need more then please let me know I will provide all as much as you need to understand. Thanks

Comment: So you have one disabled button and one enabled button for user 1, is this correct?

Comment: yes, there two rows of status in the result. we have to match the package with the resulted data and then check for each package on the page to disable and enable the package button against the status. like if the package 1 is in the tbl_lendinglogs and the status is 1 and the package 2 is also in the table and the status is 0 then the package 1's button will be disabled and the package 2's button will be remain enabled. this is i actually want.

Comment: Is there a name in the result then? That contains 'package1' or 'package2' for example

Comment: there is the package id in the result query

Comment: what do you mean by $buttons['correct_id']? It is saying:    Notice: Undefined index: correct_id in D:\Noman\Web Projects\xampp\htdocs\MLM\User\packages.php on line 143
/>

Comment: Like I said, it's not a copy paste solution. You have to fill in the correct id on the corresponding button.

Comment: I've done it in a way :) thank God. See the updated post to see the way I got myself. By the your support helps me a lot to understand it. Thanks a lot.